# Adobe Illustrator Freezes on Checking System Profile

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, parallels, adobe-illustrator, system-profile

I am trying to install Adobe Illustrator on Windows 7 running in Parallels. The installer launches but stuck at the setup screen saying "Checking System Profile". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to Adobe KB:

> This issue may occur when one of the following conditions are true:

```
* The Adobe Creative Suite 4 installer cannot launch the user interface for the installer.
* A third-party component is preventing our installer's user interface from launching.
* You are using Windows XP in Normal mode.
* The Windows Installer Service that is included with Windows XP is unregistered or damaged.
```

Resources:

[Installer freezes while checking system profile | CS4](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/407/kb407428.html)